# Heroku fails to start my app, but `foreman start` works

Tags: heroku, flask, gunicorn

I'm attempting to deploy a fairly simple Flask app to Heroku's cedar stack, but I keep seeing the following error:

```
2012-08-09T22:37:49+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2012-08-09T22:37:52+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn pytips.app:create_app() -b 0.0.0.0:42152 -w 3`
2012-08-09T22:37:53+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
2012-08-09T22:37:53+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: -c: line 0: `gunicorn pytips.app:create_app() -b 0.0.0.0:42152 -w 3'
```

And I have this as my `Procfile`:

```
web: gunicorn pytips.app:create_app() -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT -w 3
```

When I test this locally by running `foreman start`, things work just fine. Why is Heroku having problems if `foreman` is fine with it locally?

UPDATE: I've also tried testing with `heroku run`. Here's what that yields:

```
heroku run --app pytips gunicorn pytips.app:create_app() -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT -w 3
```

gives me nothing.

```
heroku run --app pytips 'gunicorn pytips.app:create_app() -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT -w 3'
```

gives me `heroku:108: command not found: -b`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My current solution is this: I escape the parentheses, e.g.,

```
web: gunicorn pytips.app:create_app\(\) -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT -w 3
```

While this totally explodes on my local box, it seems to work just peachy on Heroku's system. I am still hoping the support team at Heroku can figure out why it works in one place, but not the other. Until then, I will just test locally with the the unescaped version, then put the escapes back before pushing to Heroku.

Comment: I just used this and it fixed all my problems. Fantastic. Crazy, but fantastic!

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error 500s with nothing in the logs.

Turned out that Heroku did not like my local SQLite database. I was able to set up the free PostgreSQL database and the error went away.

I followed this tutorial.

http://blog.y3xz.com/blog/2012/08/16/flask-and-postgresql-on-heroku/

Answer (score 0):

so the first thing is your `gunicorn` command is incorrect. When you run gunicorn, you need to pass it your app instance. So for example, if your Flask app is defined inside a `pytips.py` file, you would run gunicorn by doing: `gunicorn pytips:app -b ...`.

If you change that, I'm guessing it will work fine, as the rest of your stuff looks good.

Comment: create_app() is how you get a handle to the app instance.